# In Rails' ActiveRecord, what is touch for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've heard of Rails' ActiveRecord/ActiveModel having something called "touch". However, I haven't found anything describing the purpose of this functionality.

What does it do, and what is it useful for?

Comment: Just used to "edit" a model so you know when it was last used in some relevant context.  E.g. updating a user on login so you know when they last stopped by.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As per the [API Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch), it is a method that only updates the specified timestamps of the model with the current time. So in order to update the `updated_at` field:

```
product.touch
```

or to update the `updated_at` and `designed_at` fields:

```
product.touch(:designed_at)
```

Now, I have never used this method before, but I'd think it would be useful in a situation to "bump" a question (like on Stack Overflow) to the top of a search query without actually changing the contents.

Comment: I believe they took the name from the command line utility [`touch(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html), which updates a file's modified at metadata field.

Comment: Note that, according to the documentation above, while touch does change the database row of the object it's used on, it does _not_ trigger most normal Rails callbacks.  The only callbacks triggered are `after_touch`, `after_commit`, and `after_rollback`.  `before_validation`, `after_save`, etc. are not executed after touching a model, so make sure you don't need any of the logic in them if you're using touch.

Comment: They probably updated it as no validation is executed. This is current doc says.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch#:~:text=Please%20note%20that%20no%20validation%20is%20performed%20and%20only%20the%20after_touch%2C%20after_commit%20and%20after_rollback%20callbacks%20are%20executed.

Answer (score 43):

Adding to Ryan's answer, don't forget to use touch in your models like so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library, touch: true
end
```

Now when you add a book to the library, the library's `updated_at` time will reflect the time the latest book was added! Bonus!

Answer (score 6):

`touch` can be useful if you're doing [Russian Doll caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching).

> The advantage of Russian doll caching is that if a single product is updated, all the other inner fragments can be reused when regenerating the outer fragment.
>
> If any attribute of [the inner fragment] is changed, the `updated_at` value will be set to the current time, thereby expiring the cache. However, because `updated_at` will not be changed for the [parent] object, that cache will not be expired and your app will serve stale data. To fix this, we tie the models together with the touch method.

Answer (score 3):

> Now in Rails 6 there is new method implemented called **touch_all**
>
> By that you can update the timestamp of group of collection.
>
> **Example**: If you want to update the timestamp of updated_at with current time of all the products then you can use touch_all method like this
>
> Product.touch_all

Answer (score 2):

In rails touch is used to update the `updated_at` field for persisted objects.
But if we pass other attributes as arguments, it will update those fields too along with `updated_at`. Even it will update non-date-time fields if passed as arguments.

For example

```
product.touch(:price) #price is an integer
```

will update `updated_at` of product and set price value as `Time.now.to_i`

Answer (score 1):

It's useful if you are using a front-end framework like flux (Alt/ Redux) or making async calls to the server, to update your model. In the case of multiple API calls made to your server, I used it to first check the 'updated_at' timing of a model before doing any saving or validations. Next, you can use 'touch' to update the 'updated_at' field accordingly.